BrowserWindow when created as a childWindow in Electron Application, then Selenium Not able to create Session and throwing SessionNotCreatedException
We are automating the POS application which is developed using electron. We use Selenium Java Webdriver for automating the electron application. We were able to successfully automate the electron application until developers implemented a new child window in the CFD(Customer Facing Device) screen. When developer created a new browserWindow and initialized it as a child window, selenium is unable to establish a connection with the electron application. Has anyone faced similar issues? if yes, could someone please assist me with this issue?
We tried different options, such as increase the timeout for session creation. Trying different chrome options to handle electron related complexities. But none seems to work. The application wait for the duration set and gets timeout and through SessionNotCreationException

seems like you'd need to initialize a separate driver to deal with that webview.  (these are basically separate webviews in the app, no?)
